# Using a clock for Auto click

Tags: javascript, html, clock

I am using the code below to execute an Autoclick for an interval, now I want to add the specific time to start and stop the clicking. It would be great if somebody could help me to do that. 
there is a clock in the website which the time is different from the system clock(by 1-2 seconds), so  I would prefer to use the website clock as the reference. 
I appreciate that.

```
let timerId = setInterval(() => {
    let Quant = “1000”;
    let Ptag = “10000”;

    document.getElementById("send_order_txtCount").value = Quant;
    document.getElementById("send_order_txtPrice").value = Ptag;

    $("#send_order_btnSendOrder").click();
    console.log('clicked');
}, 1000);

// 1000 is the time span to clicking (Mili seconds)
// 4000 is the total time to stop the code 

let stop = 4000;
setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    alert('stop');
}, stop);
```

Comment: setInterval and SetTimeout use an indicative duration, their execution is subject to the availability of the system

Comment: I want the code to start clicking at 14:00:00 I don't know how to that. the exact time ( in milliseconds) is important to me

Comment: as I wrote to you, there will always be a lag of a few milliseconds (or much more)

Comment: Where is the code mentioning 14:00:00 or seeking such input ? You would need to show what code effort you have put it in to seek input. Then someone can comment on that code if it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok I understand , my main problem is how to define the clock ( from system and/or server ) so the code starts at that time. starting 14:00:00:01 0r 14:00:00:200 doesn't matter. I need the code for starting at 14:00:00 . the clock should be fetched from system or server.

Comment: thank you, let me define my question prperly

Comment: You should start clicking at 8:30

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering whether this will work or not.

"Start": "9:46:56",
"Stop": "9:47:00",

Comment: How would this be used? This feels more like a comment than an answer.